# Can I pull from git to my domain host for a private website?

Tags: html, git, github, git-pull

I have a private website and I have both a domain/hosting from a provider. I have been using git to version control it to github (through git, using terminal) so I can keep track of changes, and I found it rather tedious to commit/push to git, and then zip all the files, upload them to my host, delete old ones, unzip, etc. Is there a way I can “push”  the files to both github AND my host, eliminating needless steps? My host is ASmallOrange.
I should specify that all I have is HTML, CSS and JS on it, I don't think I have a backend (that I set up at least). I just have a css folder, image folder, and index.html at the root.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what technology stack you're using, check out the deployment tool of choice for your platform. [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) for Python, [Deployer](http://deployer.org/) for PHP and, I think, [Mina](http://nadarei.co/mina/) for Ruby.

Or at least write a simple batch file that automates everything you're currently doing manually.

Comment: Oh it's a very simple basic website that uses html, css and some js. I don't have a backend set up. Not sure what a batch file is or how to write it >_>